# IIS Print PDF through CMD using acrord32.exe

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, iis, printing

I have a web application where i'm trying to print directly to a printer.
The code works locally, however, I can't seem to get it to work on the test server.

The method is as follows;

```
internal void PrintStockTransactionPdf(string documentNumber, EnStockTransactionType transType)
{
    Guid fileName = Guid.NewGuid();
    string tempFilePath = String.Format("{0}{1}.pdf", Path.GetTempPath(), fileName.ToString());
    string adobePath = this._blSettings.GetSettingByName<string>("adobeReaderPath");
    string printerPath = this._blSettings.GetSettingByName<string>("printerPath");
    string url = "";

        // Retrieve the correct PDF
     if(transType == EnStockTransactionType.StockAdjustment)
         url = string.Format(this._blSettings.GetSettingByName<string>("stockadjustmentreporturl"), "PDF", documentNumber);
     else if (transType == EnStockTransactionType.StockRelocation)
         url = string.Format(this._blSettings.GetSettingByName<string>("stockrelocationreporturl"), "PDF", documentNumber);
     else if (transType == EnStockTransactionType.StockCheckout)
         url = string.Format(this._blSettings.GetSettingByName<string>("stockcheckoutreporturl"), "PDF", documentNumber);
     else if (transType == EnStockTransactionType.StockReturn)
         url = string.Format(this._blSettings.GetSettingByName<string>("stockreturnreporturl"), "PDF", documentNumber);

    // Save temp file
    File.WriteAllBytes(tempFilePath, this._blStock.GetStockTransactionFile(url));
    Process p = new Process()
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false
        }
    };
    p.Start();

    using (StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput)
        if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
        {
            // Print command
            sw.WriteLine(@"""{0}"" /h /t ""{1}"" ""{2}""", adobePath, tempFilePath, printerPath);
            // Delay 5 seconds to allow print to complete before killing Adobe
            sw.WriteLine("ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 5000 > nul");
            // Kill Adobe
            sw.WriteLine("taskkill /F /IM acroRD32.exe");
        }

    // Delay 5 seconds server side, before removing the temp file
    if (p.HasExited == false)
        p.WaitForExit(5000);
    p.Close();

    // Remove the temp file
    File.Delete(tempFilePath);
```

I've tried redirecting the standard output, which yields the following result;

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200](c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
c:\windows\system32\inetsrv>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /h /t "C:\Windows\TEMP\b15df292-8fd5-46fb-8f8e-3427b6cc37b4.pdf" "\\<loc>\<printer>"
c:\windows\system32\inetsrv>ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 5000 > nul
c:\windows\system32\inetsrv>taskkill /F /IM acroRD32.exe
SUCCESS: The process "AcroRd32.exe" with PID 9652 has been terminated.
c:\windows\system32\inetsrv>
```

Which is all correct, and works if i run it directly through a command prompt.

The web app impersonates a user (on the server, not locally), which i've logged into the server as, and tried running the command through a cmd prompt as well (this also works).

I've also tried running a powershell command through the web app, which lists the available printers - the printer i'm trying to print to comes up as well.

Any information in rectifying this, or an alternate approach that is sure to work, would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why does it work on my local machine? (i.e. if i run the code from vs, and it runs through IIS Express). Is there no other way to achieve the final result of printing a pdf document to a specific printer from the web application?

Comment: Because IIS Express is a different beast, it is a user process, not a server process (I'm still surprised it works there). You should use a PDF component that supports printing, don't start other processes like Acrobat reader in your web page. Even such a component, if it exists, should be in a Windows service outside the IIS process and print the PDFs your web site is asking it for.

Comment: So, I would be able to move the existing code into a windows service, and then start the service from the web application instead? (Sorry, I haven't really had any experience with creating windows services). Thanks again for any info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done with Acrobat Reader, since it will always shows it's UI when printing, and you are not allowed to show a UI from a windows service. This is what you are doing when you use IIS on Windows Server.

As @PeterHahndorf mentioned in a comment, you should use a PDF component that can print the PDF for you. If a commercial component is ok for you, you can try with [Amyuni PDF Creator .Net](https://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreator/features/) (*Disclaimer: I work for Amyuni Technologies*). If a library/application with an [AGPL license](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960802/can-i-use-libraries-licensed-under-agpl-for-commercial-purposes) is ok, you can try [calling ghostscript from the command line for printing the file](https://superuser.com/questions/807027/how-to-print-with-ghostscript-in-silent-mode).

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I ended up using ghostscript to get the print method to work. What advantages are there to putting this in a windows service instead? Why should it not be called directly from the website?

Comment: About starting  external processes on your website,  depending on how many concurrent request your website will have it may indeed be a good idea to take this task out of your web page.